# Objects do not inherit bucket permissions

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In GCS storage, when adding permissions to a bucket (NOT the whole project; just a single bucket inside that project), you used to be able to set up the permissions of a bucket so that any NEW objects put in the bucket inherit the bucket's permissions.

In the newest version of the GCS however, we have not been able to figure out how to do this. We can set permissions to a root bucket:

```
{
    "email": "someuser@someaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "entity": "someuser@someaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "role": "READER"
  }
```

But then when a new object is placed in that bucket, it does not inherit this role.

Is there a way to either (a) inherit the role, or (b) set an IAM role to the bucket (we have only been able to set an IAM role to the *project*, not a specific bucket)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe relevant - the standard `Viewer` role can only be applied to a project, but `roles/storage.objectViewer` (different permissions) can be applied to a bucket. See [Standard roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles). Check the permissions for your `READER` role (which appears to be a custom one?)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. This is what I get: Command: gsutil acl ch -u user@bucket-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.objectViewer gs://bucket/
Result: CommandException: user@bucket-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.objectViewer is not a valid ACL change
Allowed permissions are OWNER, WRITER, READER

Answer (score 1):

There are five different ways to configure [Access Control options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) for Cloud Storage buckets. I suggest you the Access Control Lists (ACLs) to inherit the role in a single bucket since ACLs are used when “you need fine-grained control over individual objects”.

To change the permissions on a single bucket inside a project using the Console,

1. Go to Storage, browser. Once there you will see a bucket list.
2. Select the bucket in which you want to change the permissions.
3. Click on the three vertical dots at the right side and select "Edit bucket permissions".
4. Type the account that you want to configure and select the desired role.

The described procedure is detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl), as well as other ways to set the ACLs, as for example using the Cloud Shell. The next command specify individual grants:

```
gsutil acl ch -u [USER_EMAIL]:[PERMISSION] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Find a list of predefined roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles).

**Update 2**

Considering the next error:

> CommandException:
>   user@account.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.legacyBucketReader
>   is not a valid ACL change Allowed permissions are OWNER, WRITER,
>   READER

And the fact that there are two types of roles involved:

1. [Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview): members project oriented roles. “Defines who (identity) has what access (role) for which resource”. [Example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#give_someone_access_to_your_bucket): `gsutil iam ch user:[USER_EMAIL]:objectCreator,objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`
2. [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#top_of_page): grant read or write access to users for individual buckets or objects. [Example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl): `gsutil acl ch -u [USER_EMAIL]:READER gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`

The command is not working because both commands are mixed. For `gsutil acl`, the only possible permissions are READER, WRITER, OWNER, Default, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to have been an intermittent bug because that exact function was not available in the console yesterday (that's how we used to be doing things) and the gsutil acl ch also did not affect any newly created objects. Very weird. The console now still says "You can no longer set ACLs in the console to manage access. To learn how IAM and ACLs are related, see the documentation" but it now works. I'm even more confused now

Comment: Have you been able to fix all the storage permissions appropriately? 

If not, please let me know if you have recently changed some other related permissions besides the one referred to cloud storage reading (cloud storage admin, IAM, etc.). I have played with permissions in IAM and when the access is not allowed, the error message is clear. P.e.: 
`AccessDeniedException: 403 [EMAIL] does not have storage.buckets.get access to [BUCKET].`

Comment: This does not work. I get: CommandException: user@account.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.legacyBucketReader is not a valid ACL change
Allowed permissions are OWNER, WRITER, READER. The bucket already has READER permissions (I tried it, it said "no change") and when I create a new object in it it does *NOT* inherit the read permissions for the user.

Comment: AIM says I am the owner of the project. That has been enough for anything I needed to do so far; did it change?

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong in Update 1. You are right, owner of the project is enough. Have a look in the Update 2 (I delete the first update since leaving it could be confusing).